# absl.flags._exceptions.IllegalFlagValueError: flag --trained_checkpoint_prefix=None: Flag --trained_checkpoint_prefix must be specified

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I run:

```
python3 export_inference_graph.py \ --input_type image_tensor \ --pipeline_config_path training/logo_v1.config \ ----trained_checkpoint_prefix training/model.ckpt-250000 \ --output_directory logo_deteksi
```

And I receive the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "export_inference_graph.py", line 143, in
tf.app.run()
File "/home/dukundeath/.virtualenvs/cv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 119, in run
argv = flags.FLAGS(_sys.argv if argv is None else argv, known_only=True)
File "/home/dukundeath/.virtualenvs/cv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/flags.py", line 112, in call
return self.dict['__wrapped'].call(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/dukundeath/.virtualenvs/cv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/absl/flags/_flagvalues.py", line 635, in call
self._assert_all_validators()
File "/home/dukundeath/.virtualenvs/cv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/absl/flags/_flagvalues.py", line 509, in _assert_all_validators
self._assert_validators(all_validators)
File "/home/dukundeath/.virtualenvs/cv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/absl/flags/_flagvalues.py", line 530, in _assert_validators
raise _exceptions.IllegalFlagValueError('%s: %s' % (message, str(e)))
absl.flags._exceptions.IllegalFlagValueError: flag --trained_checkpoint_prefix=None: Flag --trained_checkpoint_prefix must be specified.
```

How to fix this?